# ESP32: unexpected voltage readings on EN and IO0

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, esp32

I am designing a PCB for the first time with the ESP32-PICO-V3 chip, but the chip doesn't boot. The chip is connected to the rest of the PCB as seen in the simplified diagram below, where I measured the voltages at EN and IO0 during my troubleshooting.

When I give my PCB power (external 5 V input that is regulated to a stable 3.4 V with a voltage regulator), I measure 2.37 V at the EN-pin and 1.8 V at IO0. From my understanding, these pins should have values closer to 3.3 V, but at least above 2.45 V to be considered "high" and boot properly.

So far I have taken out the capacitor in the RC circuit at the EN-pin to check if that corrects the voltage drop, but it doesn't. I also measured my MTDI and MTDO pins, which are 0 V (indicating that the internal regulator operates at 3.3 V) and 1.8 V (not sure why) respectively.

Does anyone have advice on how I can further troubleshoot and fix this problem?

For further clarification, I say that the chip doesn't boot because I can't communicate with it over UART. The IDE fails to connect to the board.

[image]

Comment: I see at least two Vdd pins not connected. Not sure if they need to be. Please read the data sheet if you are unsure. I also expect to see problems on your PCB (unshown).

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, thank you for your quick reply. I realised I didn't connect VDD3P3_RTC to 3.3V, which I will do ASAP. From the datasheet, I understand that it should then also power VDD_SDIO. I am not sure, but can a powered-down SDIO cause booting issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem after making two changes. The first, which I suspect might be the biggest fix, is that I decreased the soft-start delay of my voltage regulator to almost nothing. Secondly, like @Andyaka mentioned, I connected VDD3P3_RTC to 3.3V. Not only did I measure 3.3V on the EN and IO0 pins, but I can now successfully communicate with my ESP32 as well.